# How to "animate" a pgfplot picture to slide in a beamer slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, animations

I have the following beamer slide:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        ]
            \addplot[dashed, const plot mark left] coordinates {
                (0, 0)
                (1, 0)
                (2, 0)
                (3, 0)
                (4, 0)
                (5, 0)
                (6, 0)
                (7, 5)
                (8, 7)
                (9, 0)
                (10, 0)
                (11, 0)
                (12, 0)
                (13, 0)
                (14, 0)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want to have the plot shift to the right by 1 unit when I advance to the "next slide", but I want to keep the same slide number.

I could somehow fake this effect by having a bunch of continuous frames, where I just increase all the `x` coordinates in my plot by 1 unit, but there must be a better way.

Can someone suggest things that I can look into?

Comment: You cannot do without re-plotting the data for each frame. If the plot changes, underlying data must change as well. But different options are available for animating the plot sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `overlay-beamer-styles` library and use overlays to keep the same *frame number*:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        ]
            \addplot[
              dashed, 
              const plot mark left,
              alt=<2>{xshift=0.4cm}{},
              alt=<3>{xshift=0.8cm}{}
            ] coordinates {
                (0, 0)
                (1, 0)
                (2, 0)
                (3, 0)
                (4, 0)
                (5, 0)
                (6, 0)
                (7, 5)
                (8, 7)
                (9, 0)
                (10, 0)
                (11, 0)
                (12, 0)
                (13, 0)
                (14, 0)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(the value of `0.4cm` -- and multiples thereof -- might need fine tuning, this was just a rough guess)

Answer (score 3):

If the plot changes, underlying data must change as well. Underlying data can be filtered with `x filter/.expression={}` to achieve this. There is no need for manual adjustment if proper data are plotted instead of shifting the graph on the `tikzpicture` level.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,7} {\only<\i>{%
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        ]
            \addplot[
              dashed, const plot mark left,
              unbounded coords=jump,
              x filter/.expression={x+\i-1>14 ? nan : x+\i-1}
            ] coordinates {
                (-\i+1, 0)
                (0, 0)
                (1, 0)
                (2, 0)
                (3, 0)
                (4, 0)
                (5, 0)
                (6, 0)
                (7, 5)
                (8, 7)
                (9, 0)
                (10, 0)
                (11, 0)
                (12, 0)
                (13, 0)
                (14, 0)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    }}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```